# Frequency Distribution of Bigrams

Tags: python, nltk, frequency-distribution

I have done the following

```
import nltk


words = nltk.corpus.brown.words()
freq = nltk.FreqDist(words)
```

And am able to find the frequency of certain words in the brown corpus, like

```
freq["the"]
62713
```

But now I want to be able to find the Frequency Distribution of specific bigrams. So then I tried

```
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(words)
freqbig = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)
```

But every bigram that I enter, I always get 0. Like,

```
freqbig["the man"]
0
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It accepts a `tuple` as key, not a `str`:

```
freqbig[("the", "man")]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
128
```

If you want to pass strings, you could create an auxiliary function which takes care of it:

```
def get_frequency(my_string):
    return freqbig[tuple(my_string.split(" "))]
```